# Добавить к строке число в цикле

Tags: c++

Есть код который перебирает COM порты и если находит то подключается, если нет то ошибка.

```
int i = -1;
while (!libfptr_is_opened(fptr) && i < 10) {
    i++;
    libfptr_close(fptr);
    libfptr_set_single_setting(fptr, LIBFPTR_SETTING_PORT, std::to_wstring(LIBFPTR_PORT_COM).c_str());
    libfptr_set_single_setting(fptr, LIBFPTR_SETTING_COM_FILE, L"/dev/ttyS" + i);
    libfptr_apply_single_settings(fptr);
    libfptr_open(fptr);
} 
if (i == 10) {
    printf("Error = NoConnect");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Суть в том что он не складывает переменную i со строкой. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L"/dev/ttyS" + i` выполняет арифметику указателей, вам это явно не нужно.

Вместо этого подойдет что-то вроде

```
(L"/dev/ttyS" + std::to_wstring(i)).c_str()
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.